# Conflict with sublime hotkey

Tags: sublimetext3

I am working with the sublime 3 text editor. I am modifying the User version of the keymap, however, it does not seem to be replacing the default keymap hotkeys. Specifically, in the Default keymap, I see the following assigned for the "copy" hotkey:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+insert"], "command": "copy" },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+c"], "command": "copy" },
```

There are two hotkeys assigned for the copy command, and I am not sure why. I use the latter command in my User keymap, but the hotkey is not working. The ctrl+insert hotkey is the one that is taking precedence.

Is there a way to modify the Default keymap for Sublime?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see this conflict. But if you do, you can set a hotkey command to `none` if you don't want it to use.

```
{
    "keys": ["ctrl+insert"], 
    "command": "none"
},
```